# Are there significant demographic differences that explain why one specific county picked Sanders over Biden in the 2020 Democratic primary?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, demographics, democratic-primary, arkansas

Joe Biden won every county in the 2020 Arkansas Democratic primary except Washington County, which Bernie Sanders won.

I find this weird and was trying to understand why this would happen.

I'm not asking for opinion-based answers, I'm just wondering whether Washington County is demographically different from the rest of the State, in a way that explains it being an outlier.  Is it Whiter?  Does it have a large city?  Etc.

From what I can see, it seems like a pretty standard Arkansas county, home to Fayetteville.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Arkansas) it is significantly less white than the neighboring counties in the region. (80% vs 90 and 95%)

Comment: @Jontia wouldn't that make it less Sanders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Arkansas) it is significantly less white than the neighboring counties in the region. (80% vs 90 and 95%)

But has a significantly larger proportion of people in [20-24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_County,_Arkansas#Human_resources) age range due to the presence of The University of Arkansas at Fayetteville. According to [the Hill](https://thehill.com/hilltv/rising/457642-sanders-support-among-college-students-rises-to-highest-level-since-april), amongst college students there is a significant preference for Sanders over any other candidate, Biden included.

> The latest figures, released Thursday, found that 29 percent of likely Democratic voters attending college or university picked Sanders as their top choice for president. Support for Sanders in this election cycle peaked at 32 percent in April.

> Sen. Elizabeth Warren (D-Mass.) and former Vice President Joe Biden were the only other White House contenders to win double-digit support in the Democratic field. Twenty-two percent of Democratic participants picked Warren, while 10 percent chose Biden. South Bend, Ind., Mayor Pete Buttigieg (D) followed with 9 percent and former Rep. Beto O'Rourke (D-Texas) with 7 percent.

It seems likely that this is the source of Sanders' victory in the county.

Comment: So a university town.  Makes sense.